# How can i access a variable outside a future function in flutter

Tags: flutter, function, dart

This is where my widget starts, i am fetching items from a url in another file then calling it in this dart file. This fetched items are the ones displaying on the screen. What i want is to update the state of the **item.id** which is stored in current id.

```
Future<List<Items>> list =  fetchItems();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      
      // drawer: navdrawer(),

      backgroundColor: Colors.black,

      extendBody: true,
      body: Center(

        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: list,
          
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot)
          {
            if(snapshot.hasData)
              {
                return ListView.builder(
                  
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index){
                    Items item = snapshot.data[index];

                    String currentid = item.id;
```

This button has an onpress that has a set state that is supposed to update the **item.id**. This item.id is outside this future and thats the problem because it wount update it but it can print out the id

```
onPressed: () {
    setState(() {

        Future prevday() async {
            var i = int.parse(currentid);

            var nextnum = i + value2--;
            var sstring = nextnum.toString();

            var url = Uri.parse('https://insia.co.ke/test/nextday.php');
            var response = await http.post(url, body: {
            'day' : sstring,
            });

            var data2 = json.decode(response.body);
            // return data2[0];
        
            currentid = data2[0]['id'];
            var date = data2[0]['date'];
            var fajr = data2[0]['fajr'];
            var dhuhr = data2[0]['dhuhr'];
            var asr = data2[0]['asr'];
            var maghrib = data2[0]['maghrib'];
            var isha = data2[0]['isha'];
            var pic = data2[0]['pic'];
            var status = data2[0]['status'];
            var lunar = data2[0]['lunar'];
            var idate = data2[0]['idate'];

            // how can i access the above variables outside the future 
            // if i try the print outside the future it throws an error 
            //of cuurent id is undefined and the same for the other variables 
            print(currentid);

        }

        prevday();
    
    });
},
```

Comment: Since you haven't provided the `Items` class, I want to ask: Are you trying to fetch the same model(`Items`) and redraw the list when pressing the button? Or are you trying to get different data based on `id`, for example? If you could try to explain a bit more, it would be easier to help.